# How many ways are there to maintain handlebars template in client side

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, client-side-templating

In my application we are templating handlebars from client side(we are not templating from server side).So till now we used maintaining all templated inside of the `html` file using `script` tag like in the following way.

```
 <script id="selectdropdownTpl_mobile" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <option value="{{optValue}}" label="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
</script>
```

Whenever I want template, I am just compiling and appending compiled result to dom just like following way

```
var alertCompilation= Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("selectdropdownTpl_mobile").innerHTML)
alertCompilation({"optValue":"test","name":"firstApp});
```

Working fine,but what we are thinking to separate all handlebar templates into another file.so it's easy to maintain html file.

Regarding this,I thinking to move all the templates into `.js` file inside of the file just creating global variable,it is object in the following way.

```
 //fileName test.js
 var templates={
    "selectdropdownTpl_mobile":"template code"
 }
```

whenever I want, I can access template code like in the following way.

```
 var alertCompilation= Handlebars.compile(templates["selectdropdownTpl_mobile"]);
alertCompilation({"optValue":"test","name":"firstApp});
```

This way also working fine,What I want to know is this good way or not.If it is not good way How shell do this.

I heard about `.hbs` file, basically it contains `pre-compiler` template.It's usefull If I template from server side but in my case templating happening in client side itself.

can anyone suggest me,which way is better.

Comment: Why do you won't use some build system like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) with [grunt-contrib-handlebars](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars) plugin? Grunt can precompile your templates automatically in development environment, you don't need actually server for that.